# FQL multiquery python

Tags: facebook, python-3.x, fql.multiquery

Hello I'm trying to run a FQL multiquery in python 3 and failing miserably. I can run 1 query fine however when I'm trying to run a multiquery I can't get it to work. For the sake of this question I've just used a multiquery that I;ve found online.

```
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse
ACCESS_TOKEN = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'


query1 = "SELECT sex FROM user WHERE uid=me()"
query2 = "SELECT uid, name, sex FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) AND not (sex in (select sex from #user_sex))  ORDER BY name"
query = {'query1':query1,'query2':query2}

params = urllib.parse.urlencode({'q': query, 'access_token': ACCESS_TOKEN})
#print (params)

url = "https://graph.facebook.com/fql?" + params
print (url)
data = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
print(data)
```

Comment: You’re aware that FQL is deprecated, and will finally go away when API v2.0 will be disabled (August 7, 2016), right …? Doesn’t make the most sense to try and develop something new with FQL now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @CBroe said, it doesn't make sense to use FQL anymore... You can get this info in one pass with the Graph API:

```
GET /me?fields=gender,friends{id,name,gender}
```

Be aware that your friends need to use the app too, otherwise you'll not be able to retrieve their info.

Comment: Thanks guys, wasn't aware of this I'll switch to using the graph API